# How do I use findOneAndUpdate in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Running [MongDB Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com) version 4.0.6 with Mongoose 5.4.19 
I'm looping through a JSON array and trying to create or update records in the database. I tried using the findOneAndUpdate function and although it does not seem to fail, the records are not created in the database. I know that the database connects, and I know that I can create records using Save, but I can't seem to make it work with findOneAndUpdate. Below is my code, perhaps I'm not using promises correctly, or perhaps I should be using a different function?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

var it = obj[i];

var  companyJson = {
    organization_name:it["Organization Name"],
    twitter:it["Twitter"],
    facebook:it["Facebook"],
    linkedin: it["Linkedin"],
};

//var myCompany = new Company(companyJson);

var query = { organization_name: it["Organization Name"] };
var options  = {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true};

Company.findOneAndUpdate(
        {query, // find a document with that filter
        companyJson, // document to insert when nothing was found
        options, // options
            function (err, doc) { // callback
                console.log("it worked");
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error finding and updating company", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("found and updating company");
                    // console.log("found and updating company", doc);
                }
            } // callback
        }
    );

var shit = obj[i][0];
console.log('the shit',shit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding multi in options set to true.

```
var options  = {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true, multi: true};
```

By default, its value is false and mongodb operation exists after matching the first document, so this might be the reason its not creating all the documents in the database.